# mysql multiple INNER JOIN to add two table columns to another table

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, select, inner-join

**three tables**

status : ID,member_1,member_2 -->

```
(eg. 12, member_Joseph, member_John ; 
     22, member_Jacob, member_Jarrod ; 
     31, member_Jarrod, member_John 
     11, member_John, member_Jacob)
```

submit : ID,student  -->

```
(eg. 12, Amy ; 
     22, Brian; 
     31 Susan ; 
     11 Kyle)
```

info   : member_name, contact  -->

```
(eg. member_Joseph, joseph@name.name; 
     member_Jacob, jacob@name.name ; 
     member_Jarrod, jarrod@name.name ; 
     member_John, john@name.name )
```

New table to build from query:

```
 member_Joseph, joseph@name.name, Amy; 
 member_Jacob, jacob@name.name, Kyle ; 
 member_Jarrod, jarrod@name.name, Brian, Susan ; 
 member_John, john@name.name, Amy, Susan, Kyle )
```

I'd like to make arrays of all students assigned to each member in status table
eg. 
 array1 --> member_Joseph: student 1, student 2, student 3
      array2 --> member_John: student 2, student 4, student 5
       array3 -->member_Jacob: student 3, student 5, student 1

Would that be:

```
$query = db_query("
    SELECT info.member_name, submit.student  
    FROM {info} 
    INNER JOIN {status} 
    ON info.member_name = status.member_1
    INNER JOIN {status}
    ON info.member_name = status.member_2
    INNER JOIN {submit}
    ON submit.id = status.id
");
while($result = db_fetch_array($query)){
echo $result['student']; //iterate through members and print students for each
}
```

The error is: "Not unique table/alias"

(fyi: I'm using Drupal 6 syntax)

Comment: I'm thinking `{status}` is being resolved to the same alias twice, causing the error.

Comment: the thing is, i need to look into status twice to get the name of the first and second member assigned

Comment: ic, i didn't know what alias was till now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be the table `info` should be joined twice so you can get the member_name of each memberID. You also need to supply an alias for the table so they can be uniquely identified, eg

```
SELECT  a.*, 
        b.member_name memberName1,
        c.member_name memberName2,
        // other columns you might want to show
FROM    status a        
        INNER JOIN info b
            ON a.member_1 = b.member_name
        INNER JOIN info c
            ON a.member_2 = c.member_name
        INNER JOIN submit d
            ON a.ID = d.ID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: i tried to clarify that ID just indicated submit#, and member_1 and member_2 are columns that contain the members assigned to looking at submit#. thank you for the link!

Comment: @ingrid what's your question? `:D` or did the query help you?

Comment: @ingrid can you add sample records and the result you desired to get `:D` so we can work it out.

Comment: so i did this. It might make sense to restructure the tables so that I have a table with member names as columns and then fill in students from top down. Then i don't need to do this. That didn't make sense though because rows would be unrelated